# How to specify timezone in linux using C

Tags: c, linux, unix, epoch

I was trying to set the timezone of my system, and was trying to use settimeofday(), which takes a timezone struct as an argument, but just read that that struct is now obsolete (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_settimeofday.htm) How could I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Ugh, I feel really stupid.

I created a link.c and compiled it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("This is the link \n");
}
```

Created a target.c, and compiled it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("This is the target \n");
}
```

and then tried the symlink function in a test program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void main()
{
    int garbage = symlink("/home/imandhan/pythonTests/link", "/home/imandhan/pythonTests/target");
    printf(garbage);
}
```

This gives me a segmentation fault for some reason. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing this? System administration is done from command line and carefully crafted scripts, not from C.

Comment: Oh, right. returns -1. Is my symlink syntax wrong?

Comment: Um, its for an internship where they want me to write these functions for a videoconferencing device, where I set the time, timezone and stuff, based on a struct that is passed to the function. I don't completely get the big picture yet, as I just started..

Comment: @iman453 http://docs.hp.com/en/B9106-90009/symlink.2.html Check errno for the specific error.

Comment: @Vitor Oh, I didn't know what errno was. This is super useful! Thanks. 
The thing I was doing wrong was that I had already created a file with the link name...

Comment: Ok, so my manager is convinced that there is a better way of setting the timezone other than creating the link...a function of some sort maybe. I was thinking I could just set the TZ environment variable using setenv() or something. Is that a good idea? Setenv() doesn't seem to be working on my box though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`tzset(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tzset) for setting timezone for an *application*.

For the whole system - symlink `/etc/localtime` to appropriate file under `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`.

Comment: ...and for a single session / user, set the `TZ` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to make sure I get it... I want to set the timezone for the whole system in C. So would I need to find some way to symlink /etc/localtime to the file under /usr/share/zoneinfo right? Using tzset() wouldn't work..

Sorry, I'm really new to linux and don't have admin rights on my work system to try and mess with the system.

Comment: Ugh, I feel really stupid.

I created a link.c and compiled it:
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("This is the link \n");
}

Created a target.c, and compiled it:
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("This is the target \n");
}

and then tried the symlink function in a test program:
#include <unistd.h>

void main()
{
    int garbage = symlink("/home/imandhan/pythonTests/link", "/home/imandhan/pythonTests/target");
    printf(garbage);
}

This gives me a segmentation fault for some reason. Am I doing something wrong?